# How to check whether facebook is opened or not

Tags: php, facebook

1. I am very new bee to php code.I am trying to sort out code for allowing user to download the links when they are logged into facebook else ask then to login.
2. Need php code for this task to complete.Please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: php cannot detect if a user has a facebook page open, as it is a server side script not client side, even client side scripts like javascript cannot detect if you have a tab open to facebook either.

Comment: Try to look at this link, maybe this will help you: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/getting-started-web/

Comment: My Team leader asked me to use API and then chk whether user is logged in or not.But, i won't understand how to work on it.

Comment: You need to present your case more clear, what you are trying to achieve. Like Patrick Evans says, if you want to find out if the user has a facebook tab open, you can't. The PHP-code runs on a server, and doesn't know much about the browsers state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check with user session or facebook session is active or not

According to comments in [github Facebook's example](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php), This is the best way I've seen to reliably determine login/logout status.

```
if ($session) {
  try {
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
    if ($me) {
      //User is logged in
    }
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    //User is not logged in
  }
}
```

hope this will help.